# Using Eclipse IDE as a text editor for my programming language

Tags: c, eclipse, bison, flex-lexer

I created a programming language which currently runs only on command line interface. I would like it to run on Eclipse IDE. I did some research on it but could not really find accurate answers on it.

The programming language was created using flex and bison, hence, it was created using c. Instead of creating a GUI for my programming language, I decided to use Eclipse IDE instead.

After some extensive research on how to teach Eclipse to recognize my programming language, I found some results which indicated I can use CDT in Eclipse to solve this problem.

How do I go about using this CDT in Eclipse to teach it to recognize my programming language?

Comment: [Eclipse Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) is the recommended way to add new languages to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the syntax of your language differs from C/C++, consider also the following options:

- For basic language support you can extend the [**Generic Text editor**](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_genericeditor.htm) and [add a launcher](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_launch_adding.htm)
- With [**Eclipse Xtext**](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) you define your language using a grammar language and let generate Xtext the Eclipse plug-ins for you.
- For dynamic languages [Eclipse Dynamic Languages Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) might also be an option (e. g. used by [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) for PHP)
- The trend is currently moving to the ***Language Server Protocol (LSP)***, see for example [Eclipse aCute](http://www.eclipse.org/acute/) which is based on [Eclipse LSP4E](http://www.eclipse.org/lsp4e/) (Eclipse LSP connector/integration) and [Eclipse TM4E](http://www.eclipse.org/tm4e/) (for syntax highlighting): essentially, you only need to implement one LSP language server to support the IDEs and editors that understand LSP.